# Is there any shorthand way to write CGPoint, CGRect, etc?

Tags: swift, swift3

With Swift 3.0, we now declare CGPoints like so:

```
CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
```

This is, uh...kinda verbose. When you write a function that takes a CGPoint as an argument, things get ugly pretty fast:

```
myObject.callMyFunc(someVar: 1, point1: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0), point2: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2.0))
```

Is there any shorthand for structs like CGPoint and CGRect?

Comment: I mean, you can make one yourself... There isn't a shorthand in the framework I believe.

Comment: Maybe this is verbose (probably less verbose than in some other languages) but it's perfectly clean and readable.

Comment: create a CGPoint outside your call it will be more readable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments you can create your own extension.

### Extension

You can add an initializer that accepts 2 `CGFloat(s)` and doesn't require external param names

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

let point = CGPoint(1, 2)
```

### Infix Operator

You can also define your infix operator

```
infix operator ° {}
func °(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

let point = 1.1 ° 1.1
```

Comment: Swift 3 you should use .zero instead of CGPointZero

Comment: It's weird that something like this isn't built into the language, but the answer is awesome. Wish I could give more than one up vote.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend CGPoint to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol, then you could use an array literal to initialize an CGPoint:

```
view.center = [10, 20]
```

the code:

```
extension CGPoint: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: CGFloat...) {
        assert(elements.count == 2)
        self.init(x: elements[0], y: elements[1])
    }
}
```

You should handle the element count of the array well, because complier won't check it for you. Even though this method breaks the compile safety, it's a very convenient method to use.

There is already a lib ([Literal](https://github.com/leavez/Literal)) implement this for you. It have handled some fall-down situations, like pass a one-element array to a variable where CGPoint required.