# How to create shorthands for CGPoint & CGVector?

Tags: swift

I'm doing a lot of positioning and animation stuff in literals, and they're taking up a lot of space and becoming unreadable because of the verbosity.

**What I'd like to do is turn this**

```
    var xy = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
```

Into this:

```
    var xy = •(100, 100)
```

---

**Similarly, I'd like to go from:**

```
    CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 200)
```

to something like this:

```
    `(200, 200)
```

---

But I don't know how a macro-like shorthand or something like this would be done, or even if it could be done. Any pointers (puntendered) would be better than where I'm at.

I get that this is probably, for most people, less readable.

Due to the context I always know what these are. I don't need the parameter labels or function name to understand what I'm doing. And this is private animation and motion testing, there's no need for anyone else to ever understand what's going on.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629575/is-there-any-shorthand-way-to-write-cgpoint-cgrect-etc) can help. Specifically take a look at the `Infix Operator` paragraph into my answer.

Comment: you _can_ do that but you _should not_ do it.

Comment: @appzYourLife Very interesting, lead me to this in the docs: "You’re not limited to the predefined operators. Swift gives you the freedom to define your own custom infix, prefix, postfix, and assignment operators, with custom precedence and associativity values. These operators can be used and adopted in your code like any of the predefined operators, and you can even extend existing types to support the custom operators you define."

----but I can't see how to do prefix operators, which might be perfect for this, or I could be way wrong.

Comment: @holex I KNOW, I KNOW. I've seen the warnings. etc. ;) but I'm brave, and, as I say, this is a HUGE messy worksheet for animations and motion stuff. It requires lots of editing and fiddling to get/find/determine the ideal numbers, and I want to reduce scrolling as much as possible to speed up the process.

Comment: @Confused: For prefix operator take look [here](http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/)

Comment: THANK YOU! @appzYourLife that page is gold. I had it open from my searches from your first comment. But hadn't gotten down to the good bits, and wasn't encouraged by what I saw at the top of the page. But it gets GOLDEN down below. Awesome. Custom Operators are AMAZING. My code will become completely unreadable :D

Comment: @appzYourLife what makes me a little curious, I didn't see that other question about shorthands despite searching before hand, and keeping a close eye on the results when typing my title.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot define a prefix operator taking *two* parameters (unless I am overlooking something).

Comment: argh... @MartinR DOH! I'm going to go readup about them all. That there's pre, in and post operators is boggling my mind. Giddy with rush of power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) {
        self.init(x: x, y: y)
    }
}

extension CGVector {
    init(_ dx: CGFloat, _ dy: CGFloat) {
        self.init(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }
}

typealias P = CGPoint
typealias V = CGVector

let p = P(10, 10)
let v = V(10, 10)
```

But no idea about the • and ` part - I replaced them with P and V :)

Answer (score 1):

For this type of thing you would likely use a `typealias` but I don't think you will be able to create types with names as operators or symbols.

See below, I created a `typeAlias` of CGP for CGPoint, you could simply just alias it to Point if you like.

[image]

Here is some information from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID361)

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an existing type into your program. Type alias declarations are declared using the typealias keyword and have the following form:
>
> typealias name = existing type
>
> After a type alias is declared, the aliased name can be used instead of the existing type everywhere in your program. The existing type can be a named type or a compound type. Type aliases do not create new types; they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

*EDIT*

Two simple method of excluding the parameter names:

```
func cp(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

let point = cp(0,2)


extension CGPoint {
    
    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.init(x: x, y: y)
    }
}

typealias CGP = CGPoint

let point2 = CGP(1,1)
```

The first method just creates a helper function which returns a CGPoint using it's designed intialiser. The second option is the better way of doing it, you extend CGPoint and add an intializer that marks the params as non-named params (by using the _ instead of the external name)

Comment: This is very cool. I can see other uses for this, far beyond just this problem. Can I get rid of the parameter labels with this aliasing technique?

Comment: Wow. Thank YOU! Your first approach, of creating a function, that's pure, simple genius. That never occurred to me. Is there much overhead to this sort of approach? Imagine 100 of these occurring every frame.

Comment: I dont think there would be any real difference in performance to be honest, once compiled this would be just as quick as calling the init on CGPoint, may use a tiny bit more memory

Answer (score 1):

You can't use special characters as the compiler would not be able to differentiate between function names and operators like '*'.

**Using `typealias`**

using a typealias would allow you to shorten the function name but not omit the parameter names like you outlined in your question.

```
typealias p = CGPoint
//example
let p1 = p(x: 60, y: 60)
```

**Using anonymous parameters**

```
func p(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: x,y: y)
}

//example
let p1 = p(60, 60)    //no parameter names
```

Answer (score 1):

I too like to get rid of the parameter labels, but I don't advise reducing things to any briefer shorthand. I paste this code into the start of *all* my app projects:

```
extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}
extension CGSize {
    init(_ width:CGFloat, _ height:CGFloat) {
        self.init(width:width, height:height)
    }
}
extension CGPoint {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y)
    }
}
extension CGVector {
    init (_ dx:CGFloat, _ dy:CGFloat) {
        self.init(dx:dx, dy:dy)
    }
}
```

That allows me to say things like `CGPoint(1,4)`, and that's good enough, in my opinion.

Comment: And please file a bug with Apple telling them that they were wrong to abolish `CGRectMake`, `CGPointMake`, and so on! I can't imagine what they were thinking.

Comment: Ha! Proving, once again, that anyone that rides bikes has a sense of humour built in!